# OpenERP Version 7 Invoice Tasks Work?

Tags: odoo

Is there documentation on what is required to setup Invoice Tasks Work for OpenERP version 7 like there is [here](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/book/4/4_13_Projects/4_13_Projects_management.html) for version 6.1?

Comment: My experience says its same in their functionality in both versions.

Comment: Where exactly did you find the Billing tab on the Project?

Answer (score 1):

Projects are now having their own "Contract" which is basically an analytic account. You can invoice this analytic account from Accounting Menu.

Comment: Version 7 has no "Accounting Menu" that I have been able to find.